# 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found, error

Tags: ios, flutter, cocoapods

I having some error when I run on iOS device.

This error... make me can not work on my app for a weeks.... I am trying to solve it for a week.. still I am stuck on this. I Think which is happening after x code 13.

Plz let me know what is wrong with this error. I am waiting for your help.

Thanks for reading.

```
Launching lib/main.dart on DAEGIL의 iPhone in debug mode...
Signing iOS app for device deployment using developer identity: "Apple Development: DAEGIL PYO (Q3WA3VMML7)"
Xcode build done.                                            8.3s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    2021-09-30 16:34:27.819 xcodebuild[30636:383330] CFURLRequestSetHTTPCookieStorageAcceptPolicy_block_invoke: no longer implemented and should not be called
    --- xcodebuild: WARNING: Using the first of multiple matching destinations:
    { platform:iOS, id:dvtdevice-DVTiPhonePlaceholder-iphoneos:placeholder, name:Any iOS Device }
    { platform:macOS, arch:arm64, variant:Designed for [iPad,iPhone], id:00008103-001444810A31001E }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:dvtdevice-DVTiOSDeviceSimulatorPlaceholder-iphonesimulator:placeholder, name:Any iOS Simulator Device }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:EDAD5055-209E-43BF-A48F-F0A2D8D26F43, OS:15.0, name:iPad (9th generation) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:6D279D6B-91AD-43A0-ADEA-9C19BDE7F867, OS:15.0, name:iPad Air (4th generation) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:CB7171EA-2225-4747-9F52-701A93AAEB11, OS:15.0, name:iPad Pro (9.7-inch) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:5142D23C-2C4B-4A12-B1D7-0F50CC53106F, OS:15.0, name:iPad Pro (11-inch) (3rd generation) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:3C74123E-BC00-4D28-B2F4-F76E0CACDF7C, OS:15.0, name:iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (5th generation) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:FB6CB2E0-F4D7-49C9-96F5-AD4A9C5D142F, OS:15.0, name:iPad mini (6th generation) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:6B2EBF24-9E52-49C1-A11E-B41DFEF488B5, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 8 }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:7FBEFA6E-7F73-4EDD-9ED6-E3F4ADA07594, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 8 Plus }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:5052D38E-6406-437B-8768-4D94AD187A7F, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 11 }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:02D10359-328E-4863-A07F-A5B2F3D128BE, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 11 Pro }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:0DD09E94-836C-445C-80FF-E3638CE49F1A, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 11 Pro Max }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:DCFEC142-0FD1-4796-818F-A4FA4F1A2534, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 12 }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:8D4C4C17-B329-4FD3-B4F2-4A5A049B7C3F, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 12 Pro }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:58970621-D588-4904-B2F5-79C74A9AFC2E, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 12 Pro Max }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:2C1D0A4C-95BE-4476-8135-5CA2AD5FF105, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 12 mini }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:F6FC7662-3118-485F-A613-5BF9BF50C45A, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 13 }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:211B26BA-8FE6-44DB-9240-052F8679C4AD, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 13 Pro }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:6500BCAE-6A58-4C85-B929-5AA61506EF4B, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 13 Pro Max }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:31F77AF0-F029-450C-82DE-36EBEA06237C, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 13 mini }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:777A2E59-4F4C-4016-845B-B0942CD82224, OS:15.0, name:iPhone SE (2nd generation) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:986504B0-5A78-4148-8051-C0489CDAAB37, OS:15.0, name:iPod touch (7th generation) }
    ** BUILD FAILED **
Xcode's output:
↳
    Command CompileSwiftSources failed with a nonzero exit code
    Command CompileSwiftSources failed with a nonzero exit code
    In file included from /Users/daegilpyo/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/path_provider-1.6.28/ios/Classes/FLTPathProviderPlugin.m:5:
    /Users/daegilpyo/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/path_provider-1.6.28/ios/Classes/FLTPathProviderPlugin.h:5:9: fatal error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found
    #import <Flutter/Flutter.h>
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
    note: Using new build system
    note: Planning
    note: Build preparation complete
    note: Building targets in parallel
Could not build the precompiled application for the device.

Error launching application on DAEGIL의 iPhone.
Exited (sigterm)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Try this steps :

**if you have intel chip**

1. flutter clean
2. update all dependencies to the latest version in pubspec.yml file and do 'get pub'
3. Go to your Podfile and uncomment #platform :ios, '9.0' Then change the version to 10 platform :ios, '10.0'
4. go to ios folder through terminal and do 'pod repo update'
5. 'pod update' or 'pod install'

**if you have M1 chip**

1. flutter clean
2. update all dependencies to the latest version in pubspec.yml file and do 'get pub'
3. Go to your Podfile and uncomment #platform :ios, '9.0' Then change the version to 10 platform :ios, '10.0'
4. go to ios folder through terminal and do 'arch -x86_64 pod repo update'
5. 'arch -x86_64 pod update' or 'arch -x86_64 pod install'

**OR**

Please Add into your podfile

```
  post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target| 
     flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
    end
  end
```

1. flutter clean
2. pub get
3. Go to your Podfile and uncomment #platform :ios, '9.0' Then change the version to 10 platform :ios, '10.0'
4. go to ios folder through terminal and do 'pod install' if you have **M1 Chip** do 'arch -x86_64 pod install'
5. run your project